# Lambda expressions and nested arrays

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to come up with some nice lambda expressions to build "desiredResult" from "customers" ArrayList. I implemented it in an old ugly way "for" loop. I know there should be nice one-liners, but I can't think of any method - nested arrays come into my way.

```
Iterable<List<?>> params;
Customer customer1 = new Customer("John", "Nowhere");
Customer customer2 = new Customer("Alma", "Somewhere");
Customer customer3 = new Customer("Nemo", "Here");
Collection<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
customers.add(customer1);
customers.add(customer2);
customers.add(customer3);

Collection<List<?>> desiredResult = new ArrayList<>();
for (Customer customer : customers) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(customer.getName());
    list.add(customer.getAddress());
    list.add("VIP");
    desiredResult.add(list);
}
params = desiredResult;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use `Arrays.asList` for creating the inner lists, which makes the problem much simpler:

```
Collection<List<?>> desiredResult = 
    customers.stream()
             .map(c -> Arrays.asList(c.getName(), c.getAddress(), "VIP"))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you absolutely must have an `ArrayList`, just wrap the `Arrays.asList` call with it.

Comment: End result must be Iterable<List<?>>. Anything else can be changed/improved. What would be option without ArrayList?

Comment: @PutinasPiliponis as I've shown - my code does not use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Understood :) Question closed. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion:

```
Collection<List<?>> desiredResult = customers.stream()
         .map(MyClass::customerToList)
         .collect(toList());
```

I have extracted the list building into a separate method for better readability - the corresponding method would look like this:

```
private static List<Object> customerToList(Customer c) {
  List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(c.getName());
  list.add(c.getAddress());
  list.add("VIP");      
  return list;
}
```